# Adding to mongoDB by hitting Java Endpoint with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb, rest, endpoint

I'll be pretty impressed if you guys can answer this. Basically I'm working on a full stack web app that has the following three components:

1. A collection of Articles in MongoDB
2. A backend written in Java 8
3. A front end in Javascript

The flow of the program should work as follows:

1. The user opens the webpage inputs text into a form specifying the title, authors, genre, and content.
2. When they click the "addArticle" button, it should serialize the data into raw JSON and send it to my addArticle endpoint.
3. The data is then sanitized, and it should submit this article into the database.

**I'm running into multiple problems. They are as follows:**

1. Javascript keeps refreshing the page when I click the submit button, even though I have `$(document).on("submit", "#add-Article", function(e) {e.preventDefault();}` (See *relevant code* below).
2. It doesn't look like it's hitting the endpoint at all.
3. Nothing is saved in the database

**Here's what I know works and Here's what I've tried:**

1. I've tested this through Postman and have been able to successfully add to the *articles* collection.
2. I managed to put an *alert* into the beginning of main.js, so I know it's connecting to javascript.
3. After doing a ton of research, I've found that I can just use straight JavaScript to do something like *articles.save* off of the front end. The problem with this is that I want the data to go into Java so I can sanitize it and so it will increment ObjectIds.

**Here's the relevant code**

*form*

```html
<form id="add-article">
   <input type="text" id="title"/>
   <label for="title">Title </label>
   <input type="text" id="authors"/>
   <label for="authors">Author(s) </label>
   <input type="text" id="genre"/>
   <label for="genre">Genre </label>
   <input type="text" id="content"/>
   <label for="content">Content </label>
   <button id="addArticle">Submit Article for Peer Review</button>
  </form>
```

*Javascript*

```js
alert('JS is linked to page!');

function Article(Id = 1, Title = "", Authors="", Content = "", Genre = "", Date = 1497484623) {
    console.log("JavaScript file loaded successfully");
    var self = this;
    self.Id = Id;
    self.Title = Title;
    self.Authors = Authors;
    self.Content = Content;
    self.Genre = Genre;
    self.Date = Date;
    self.Save = function() {
        var settings = {
            url: 'localhost:8080/articles/addArticle/',
            method: 'POST'
        };
        var myData = {
            "Title": self.Title,
            "Authors": self.Authors,
            "Content": self.Content,
            "Genre": self.Genre,
            "Date": self.Date
        };
        settings.data = myData;
 
        $.ajax(settings).done(function(Article) {
         var myArticle = new Article(Article.Id, Article.Title, Article.Authors,
                Article.Content, Article.Genre, Article.Date);
            CreateSuccessRow(myArticle);
        });
    };
}

    $(document).on("submit", "#add-Article", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            alert('submit Activated');
        var title, authors, genre, content;
        title = $("#title").val();
        director = $("#authors").val();
        rating = $("#genre").val();
        notes = $("#content").val();
        var myArticle = new Article(title, authors, genre, content);
        alert(myArticle.title);
        addArticle(myArticle);
        //$("#add-article")[0].reset();
        $("#title").focus();
 
    });

function addArticle(Article) {
    alert('addArticle Activated');
    var settings = {
        url: 'localhost:8080/articles/addArticle',
        method: 'POST'
    };
    var myArticle = {  
  "Title": Article.Title,     
  "Authors" : Article.Authors,
  "Content": Article.Content,
  "Genre" : Article.Genre,
  "Date": 1497484623 
    };
    settings.data = myArticle;
 
    $.ajax(settings).done(function(Article) {
        var myArticle = new Article(Article.Title, Article.Authors, Article.Content,
            Article.Genre, Date);
  //CreateArticleRow(myArticle);
        console.log("Article Created");
    });
}
```

*Controller Endpoint*

```
`@RestController
```

@RequestMapping("/articles")
public class ArticleController {

```
private ArticleRepo articleRepo;

@Autowired
public ArticleController(ArticleRepo articleRepo) {
    this.articleRepo = articleRepo;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addArticle", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Article addArticle(@RequestBody Article newArticle) {
//sanitizing happens here
    articleRepo.save(newArticle);
    return newArticle;
}
```

}`

I've been on this same problem for over a day now and if someone could help me I'd really appreciate it. I'm assuming there's something wrong with the Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

your jquery selector does not match the html code (add-Article instead of add-rticle). jquery selectors appear to be case sensitive

```
    $(document).on("submit", "#add-article", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        alert('submit Activated');
    var title, authors, genre, content;
    title = $("#title").val();
    director = $("#authors").val();
    rating = $("#genre").val();
    notes = $("#content").val();
    var myArticle = new Article(title, authors, genre, content);
    alert(myArticle.title);
    addArticle(myArticle);
    //$("#add-article")[0].reset();
    $("#title").focus();

});
```

Comment: Thanks! This has definitely stopped the page from refreshing. I'm going to try and continue to troubleshoot and see where I can get from here.